# Using special character ^ or ¨ in python 3 idle crashes the program

Tags: crash, python-3.x, character, special-characters, python-idle

When I use these specials characters `^` or `¨` in python IDLE version 3, it makes the program crash.

I'm French and so I use these specials characters in my description or comments in my code.
Is there a way to use it without crashing the program?

Thanks !

Comment: You probably need to provide more specific information about the "crash".

Comment: Carrots "^" are perfectly fine, they're even valid tokens in a program (although I forget what they do, probably a bitwise xor).  Although I'm guessing that the carrots become grave accents over letters, right?  The basic answer is, don't EVER use special characters in your source code.  And if you want your program to output them on a display or something, use an escape sequence.

Comment: I disagree with @AJMansfield here -- I think you should go ahead and use special characters in your code, after specifying the encoding (pref. UTF-8) as per [PEP-263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).  If IDLE is crashing then that is a problem with either the program or, more likely, your configuration (env variables etc) that needs to be addressed.

Comment: Also: Don't use IDLE. It's weird. We get loads of newbie questions at SE about IDLE, it's more confusing than helpful. Get a real IDE instead.

Comment: Yes, using `°` (degree character) in the comments crashes IDLE when trying to save the file and all recent changes are lost.

Answer (score 1):

Many language specifications, and most compilers, specifically recommend against using special characters because of problems like this.

However, from http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html

> New in version 2.3: An encoding declaration can be used to indicate
>   that string literals and comments use an encoding different from
>   ASCII.

So include that declaration, and it *should* work.

If you already have such a declaration, the problem may then be not because of the characters themselves, but because of the way your setup combines the ^ and ¨ accents with other characters.  Although at that point, I'm really just shooting in the dark.